# Save data from form to Django admin database

Tags: django

`>>> django.__version__
'2.0.4'`

I'm trying to create a simple form with name and email.
I read this link - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/
But I can't figure out how to save data from the form.

forms.py

```
class SubscribeForm(forms.Form):
    your_name = forms.CharField(label='Your name', max_length=100)
    your_email = forms.EmailField(label='Your email', max_length=100)
```

views.py

```
def subscribe(request):
    """
    View for form subscribe
    """
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SubscribeForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            data_sub = form.save(commit=False)
            data_sub.save()
    else:
        form = SubscribeForm()

    return render(request, 'subscribe/subscribe.html', {'form': form})
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models


class Subscriber(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, default="")
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

But, `data_sub = form.save` is not right, if I right understand it because I use `forms.Form`.
`form.cleaned_data` - I have to use to save data, but I don't understand how to do it.

I hope for your help, thank you.

Comment: you should just be able to do `form.save()` directly after you `if form.is_valid()`

Comment: @HenryM you mean that I did everything right?

Comment: looks okay to me - have you tried it?

Comment: @HenryM I use web form in a browser(enter the name and email address and press send). Then I check Django admin and can't see the data.

Comment: what does your template look like?

Comment: Sorry, I just realised you've not used a model form.  There is no database model for this because it is not a `modelForm`

Comment: @HenryM I add models.py

Comment: @HenryM https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/#the-template - is my template

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168680/discussion-between-asergey-and-henrym).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am editing views.py

```
    if form.is_valid():
        obj = Subscriber()
        obj.name = form.cleaned_data['your_name']
        obj.email = form.cleaned_data['your_email']
        obj.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/subscribe/thanks')
```

And all work.

Answer (score 0):

```
class SubscribeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    model = Subscriber
    fields=['name','email']
```